# dlv debug error: could not launch process: fork/exec ./demo function not implemented

Tags: go, debugging, exec, goland, dlv

I encounter error when I launched a dlv debug process in docker with Goland IDE. Could anyone give me some help or has encountered this same issue?

```
root@d91e9c7df361:/workdir/demo# dlv --listen=:40000 --headless=true --api-version=2 --accept-multiclient exec ./bin/demo -- s

API server listening at: [::]:40000

2022-12-09T07:27:18Z warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)

could not launch process: fork/exec /workdir/demo/bin/demo: function not implemented
```

Go version: go version go1.18.3 linux/amd64

dlv version:
Delve Debugger
Version: 1.20.0
Build: $Id: 8ec46ee3d275c276b8e7465d69a23399e0e14789 $

build command:

```
go build -gcflags="all=-N -l" -o bin/demo ./demo.go
```

Goland version: GoLand 2022.3

1. reinstall the dlv in go docker container
2. rebuild go code
3. only exec `exec ./bin/demo -- s` working

Comment: Can you attach a project sample to reproduce it?